# React component not updating when button pressed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm just learning react at the moment, I have built a layout page and then display images using a component. Inside the component, each image has a button. this button deletes the image from the API.

But although the API call is working, and the image is deleted from the database, its not removing that image component from the layout.

Im using axios to interact with the API. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My layout code is as follows;

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from 'axios';
import ImageComponent from './components/ImageComponent';

class ImageOverview extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            imageData: []
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('http://api.com/getAllImages')
            .then(res => {
                const imageData = res.data;
                this.setState({ imageData });
            })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <>
                <div className="content">
                    <Row>
                        <Col lg="12">
                            <Card>
                                <CardBody>
                                    <Row>
                                        { this.state.imageData.map(image =>
                                            <ImageComponent
                                                key={image.id}
                                                image={image}
                                            />
                                        )}
                                    </Row>
                                </CardBody>
                            </Card>
                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                </div>
            </>
        )
    }
}

export default ImageOverview;
```

and my component code is here;

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from 'axios';

class ImageComponent extends Component {

    deleteImage(id)
    {
        axios.delete('http://api.com/deleteimage' + id)
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res);
            })
    }

    render() {
        const { image } = this.props;

        return (
            <>
                <Col className="col-xs-6 col-xs-6">
                    <Card className="h-80">
                        <CardImg top width="100%" src={'http://imagelocation.com/' + image.filename} alt="Card image cap" />
                        <CardBody>
                            <Button color="danger" size="sm" onClick={() => this.deleteImage(image.id)}><i className="icon-simple-remove" /> Delete</Button>
                        </CardBody>
                    </Card>
                </Col>
            </>
        )
    }
}

export default ImageComponent;
```

Comment: After successful delete you need to remove the given image from `this.state.imageData` array of parent component too. Since you can't change state of parent from child, move the `deleteImage` method to parent and pass it down as prop to `ImageComponent`. Once you have lot of data and components and it starts getting to complex to pass stuff down to child as props, you might wanna maintain a global state using [Redux](https://redux.js.org/), but don't worry about it just yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to actually update the state belonging to the Layout component. Specifically, you need to delete the specific image from the `imageData` array. That will trigger a re-render of the component to reflect your changes.

In **Layout.js**, create an event-handler that will delete the specific image:

```
deleteImageInState = (id) => {
   const { imageData } = this.state
   const newImageData = imageData.filter((img) => img.id !== id)
   this.setState({
     imageData: newImageData
   })
}
```

The function above simply creates a new `imageData` list that will not include the image that was deleted.

Then pass that function down to your `ImageComponent` as a prop, like you have within the `.map()` logic.

```
<ImageComponent 
    key={image.id} 
    image={image} 
    deleteImageInState ={this.deleteImageInState}
/>
```

Lastly update the `deleteImage` function you defined in **ImageComponent.js** to call the prop change-handler upon deletion.

```
deleteImage = (id) => {
    axios.delete('http://api.com/deleteimage' + id)
        .then(res => {
            this.props.deleteImageInState(id)
        })
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the `deleteImage(id)` method in the parent component `ImageOverview` and pass it as props to the child `ImageComponent`:

```
<ImageComponent key={image.id} image={image} deleteHandler={this.deleteImage.bind(this}} />
```

Inside the `deleteImage(id)` call `this.setState()` to trigger the re-render once the image has been deleted, this is what you were missing without the change in `state` through `setState()` the component won't re-render with the new data:

```
deleteImage(id)
    {
        axios.delete('http://api.com/deleteimage' + id)
            .then(res => {
                this.setState({}) //delete the image from imageData array
            })
    }
```

You can call the `deleteImage(id)` as follows in the child component:

```
<CardBody>
        <Button color="danger" size="sm" onClick={() => this.props.deleteHandler(image.id)}><i className="icon-simple-remove" /> Delete</Button> 
</CardBody>
```